# Can sql multi query be considered an atomic instruction?

Tags: php, mysql

For the php implementation point of view, is the multi_query an atomic instruction on the data base or all it does is executing all queries sequentially?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It executes queries sequentially.

Comment: Just to clarify, does it execute sequentially on php side (it splits in different queries before requesting the DB) or is it done on the DB side?

Many thanks